# Excel data sometimes does not refresh using python

Tags: python, excel, vba, python-2.7

Having sometimes issues with my excel. That data is refreshed using Python script:

```
try:
        current_date = datetime.date.today()
        deadline= datetime.date.today()+ timedelta(days=1)
        current_date_delta = current_date+datetime.timedelta(days=1)

        from win32com.client import Dispatch
        Application = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        Application.Visible = 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbook = Application.Workbooks.Open('\\\\files\\MY_FILE.xlsb')
        Application.Run('Refresh')
        Workbook.Save()
        Workbook.SaveAs('\\\\files\\MY_FILE_UPD '+ str(current_date)+'.xlsb')
        Workbook.Close()
        Application.Quit()
except:
    log_error()
```

However,
This scripts does not work time to time(not always,random) at it gives that error. So what can cause that sometimes script works and sometimes it does not? 
That excel file is not opened by somebody else while script is running.

> ERROR:root:2016.11.04 09.49 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "debts2.pyw", line 39, in 
>       Application.Run('Refresh')   File "", line 14, in Run   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 282,
>   in *ApplyTypes*
>       result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args) com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote
>   procedure call failed.', None, None)

Comment: Are you using the Excel UI when these errors occur?  If Excel has the focus in the formula bar or has a dialog open, automation calls can fail (I'm not on a Windows machine right now, so I can't check to see if the errors match yours).

Comment: what does it mean "excel has focus in formula bar"? That excel is not used by anyone, only that srcipt tries to refresh it. However, when it fails and i try to update it manually excel usually freezes or takes almost half an hour while it goes on. And it stalls on "connecting to database" notification, but DB works fine, there is no lag when i launch same query through Oracle